# Sorting by (x,y) coordinates with an offset causes violation of comparator contract

Tags: java, sorting, collections, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to sort a collection of x and y points with an offset on x such that p.x-q.x should be treated equal IF p.x==q.x OR ABS(p.x-q.x) < offset.
Note that I'm taking the absolute value here, so I shouldn't be getting any negative values. My comparator is below:

```
 private static class XYOrder implements Comparator<ExtractPojo> {

    public int compare(ExtractPojo p, ExtractPojo q) {

        Integer a=p.x.intValue();
        Integer b=q.x.intValue();
        Integer c=p.y.intValue();
        Integer d=q.y.intValue();

        int offset=Math.abs(a-b); //calculate offset from x


      if(offset < 15 || a == b) //if x is the same, sort by y coordinate
            return c-d; 
       else return a-b; //if x is not same sort by x coordinate

    }
}
```

This code works for some cases, but I get the following error message on others:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:868)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:485)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:426)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:223)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
```

I have a feeling I'm violating a transivity rule as I've searched extensively through this site for an answer, but I'm not exactly sure how to test what I'm missing here.

I've tested this code without the offset and I don't get this error message, so I know it has to do with how I'm implementing the offset. I've Been trying to solve this for a few weeks with no luck.

I was hoping to get some tips or suggestions on this. Thank you very much.

So the only fix I can think of is first sorting by x position, then going through each x and adjusting the x's to be the same based on the offset, then doing the sort again by the x,y mentioned above without the offset. Just seems like a hack to do it that way, but I've never used a comparator before and I'm having difficulty solving this issue.

Comment: `if(offset < 15 || a == b)`: `a == b` means that `offset` is 0 which is included in the condition of `< 15`.

Comment: Give some of the example cases in which this fails

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't give an example where this fails because I'm parsing enormous files which is why it's difficult to see where this blows up.

Comment: @VinceEmigh `mergeHi` is not a method implemented by OP ...

Comment: user1803551, if I just use the condition if (offset < 15) and remove (a==b), I still hit the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

> I have a feeling I'm violating a transivity rule

Indeed you are. Under your comparator, we have `(0, 20) > (10, 10) > (20, 0) > (0, 20)`. (Also, it's spelled "transitivity".)

Generally, `compare`, `compareTo`, and `equals` methods shouldn't use tolerances, because tolerances are inherently intransitive. Two differences that both fall beneath a tolerance may add up to a difference above the tolerance.

Comment: user2357112, sorry for the spelling mistake. Do you have suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: @Mac: Pick a different sort criteria that avoids comparisons up to a tolerance. Maybe group x values into bins and compare them by bin.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code again. This is what the Java docs have to say regarding the implementation of the `compare()` method.

> The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements S is said to be consistent with equals if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 in S.

Did you override the `equals()` method for your `ExtractPojo` class? You can find the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Also, you shouldn't be using code like `a == b`. Here, you have variables of type `Integer`. As such, it will only be checking whether the 2 variables point to the same object (which **could** be false in this case. More on that [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/05/java-mistake-3-using-instead-of-equals.html)). Use a.equals(b) instead.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and no I'm no overriding equals. I'll let you know how that works out.

Comment: Even if I just use primitives instead of the object Integer, it still fails Pubudu

Comment: Did you override the `equals()` method? The possible reason I can think of for the exception that you are getting is that the notion of equality in your `equals()` method and the `compare()` method of the comparator is inconsistent. For example, consider the case where `a` equals `b` (say 1000). According to the logic of your `compare()` method, it should return `0` (which means that the 2 `ExtractPojo` objects are equal).

Comment: But since you haven't overridden the `equals()` method, it will use the default `equals()` method provided by the `Object` class and this method returns true if and only if the 2 variables `a` and `b` refer to the **same** object.

Comment: Ok.. Checked it with the overridden `equals()`. Not working :/ Guess you'll have to come up with a fix for the issue user2357112 has pointed out..

Answer (score 0):

So I did a few more tests and I believe found your issue: **Overflows**.

I made your compare method very simple and I was still getting that error:

```
public int compare(ExtractPojo p, ExtractPojo q) {
    Integer x1 = p.x.intValue();
    Integer x2 = q.x.intValue();
    return x1 - x2;
}
```

This is because in some situations x1 - x2 will cause an overflow violating transitivity. To check for this do something like:

```
public int compare(ExtractPojo p, ExtractPojo q) {
    Integer x1 = p.x.intValue();
    Integer x2 = q.x.intValue();
    checkSubtractionOverflow(x1, x2);
    return x1 - x2; 
}

//This will throw an exception if there is an overflow  
public static void checkSubtractionOverflow(int left, int right) {
    Math.subtractExact(left, right);
}
```

If you see the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow
at java.lang.Math.subtractExact(Unknown Source)
```

Then you know you have overflow issues which will need to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your code is saying this:

- If the x coordinates are within 15 units of each other, use the y coordinates for comparison.
- If the x coordinates are 15 or more units from each other, use the x coordinates for comparison
- The  x coordinates are equal case can go to either side without affecting the issue at hand.

I suspect the transitivity issue is going to be hit, for example, when:

- P.x is within 15 units of Q.x and P < Q (because P.y < Q.y)
- Q.x is within 15 units of R.x and Q < R (because Q.y < R.y)
- AND P.x is beyond 15 units from R.x and P > R (because P.x > R.x)

Also, you are doing some unnecessary boxing/unboxing with the `.intValue()` calls.  `Integer a = P.x` is an Integer to Integer assignment.